# reading a file line by line and appending into a variable with semicolon in between

Tags: shell, loops, unix

I have a .txt file containing mail addresses like

```
a@xyz.com  
b@xyz.com  
c@xyz.com
```

I need to pass a variable which contains values for eg

```
$MAIL_ID=a@xyz.com;b@xyz.com;c@xyz.com;
```

I came up with something like

```
cat mail_list.txt | for MAIL_ID in $(cat ${1});
do
TEMP=' '
$ID=$MAIL_ID";"$TEMP
done
echo $ID
```

pls help with this

Comment: Why do you need to put it in a variable?  Whoever is consuming the variable can probably work with the file more easily.  Putting the data in a variable in the format you desire is pretty trivial (eg `MAIL_ID=$(tr \\n \; < input.txt)`), but I strongly suggest you re-evaluate whether it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `paste`:

```
paste -s -d\; file.txt
```

and use it to fill your variable:

```
ID=$(paste -s -d\; file.txt)
```

if your input file contains unwanted blank characters (like in your example), you can use the following:

```
ID=$(paste -s -d\; <(sed 's/ *$//' file.txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Each entry need to be appended to $ID. Try this

```
ID=""
while read MAIL_ID
do
    ID=$ID";"$MAIL_ID
done < mail_list.txt
ID=$(echo $ID | cut -c2-)
echo $ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MAIL_ID=''
while read email; do
  MAIL_ID=$MAIL_ID$email';'
done <a.txt

echo $MAIL_ID
```

Output

```
a@xyz.com;b@xyz.com;c@xyz.com;
```